# Can some one provide a link to create a simple http server and client using node js

Tags: node.js, client

Can some one provide a link to create a simple server and client using node js

Comment: Happy to.. http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these resources helpful: ["The Node Beginner Book"](http://www.nodebeginner.org/), [Building your first node.js app (series)](http://www.jblotus.com/2011/05/28/building-your-first-node-js-app-part-1-installing-node-on-windows-7/), ["NowJS and Node.js Tutorial – Creating a multi room chat client"](http://www.adityaravishankar.com/2011/10/nowjs-node-js-tutorial-creating-multi-room-chat-server/), ["Beginner’s Guide To Node.Js"](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/node-js-server-side-javascript/), and ["Node.js & WebSocket - Simple chat tutorial"](http://martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial).  These should get you up to speed with using Node.JS  Good luck!